# Powershell: add column with value retrieved from a regex hash table

Tags: powershell, csv

I am new to Powershell, and I am trying to add a column to a csv file based on a specific column and another CSV file containing a list of regex and associated value.

I could make some improvements reading many posts about Import-Csv and Select-Object.

The first matching value should be used to populate the new column, named "preference" in this scenario.

**INPUT**

*data.csv*

```
id name    first_name
-- ----    ----------
35 ALPHA   UNIFORM   
48 BRAVO   VICTOR    
39 CHARLIE WHISKEY   
42 DELTA   X-RAY     
59 ECHO    YANKEE    
64 FOXTROT ZULU
```

*regex.csv*

```
regex_key preference
--------- -----   
LP        MUSIC 
VO        VSOP
CH        CHORIZO 
.*        OTHER
```

**OUTPUT with single regex : OK**

*first_attempt.ps1*

```
$single_preference = Import-Csv .\data.csv |`
                     Select-Object *,
                                   @{Name='preference';
                                     Expression={if($_.name -match "CH"){"CHORIZO"} else {"OTHER"}}
                                    } |`
                     Export-Csv -Path ".\first_attempt_output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

*first_attempt_output.csv*

```
id name    first_name preference
-- ----    ---------- ----------
35 ALPHA   UNIFORM    OTHER     
48 BRAVO   VICTOR     OTHER     
39 CHARLIE WHISKEY    CHORIZO   
42 DELTA   X-RAY      OTHER     
59 ECHO    YANKEE     CHORIZO   
64 FOXTROT ZULU       OTHER
```

**OUTPUT using multiple regexes: stuck**

*expected_result.txt*

```
id name    first_name preference
-- ----    ---------- ----------
35 ALPHA   UNIFORM    MUSIC    
48 BRAVO   VICTOR     VSOP   
39 CHARLIE WHISKEY    CHORIZO
42 DELTA   X-RAY      OTHER   
59 ECHO    YANKEE     CHORIZO
64 FOXTROT ZULU       OTHER
```

How can I modify the code above to be able to iterate over the regex_keys and get the expected result?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd iterate through the patterns using `foreach` (not using `Foreach-Object` to not override `$_` but you can modify to match your preferences):

```bsh
$data = Import-Csv .\data.csv -Delimiter ';'
$patterns = Import-Csv .\regex.csv -Delimiter ';'
$data | Select-Object *,@{Name='preference';Expression={
  foreach ($p in $patterns) {
    if ($_.name -match $p.'regex_key') {
      $p.preference
      break
    }
  }
}}
```

In `if`, if any match is detected, I use `break` to stop loop execution.